# largest leaf node in a tree.how to prevent getting a 0 when leaf nodes are negative

Tags: c

I have to find the largest leaf node in a BST but it only has the shape of a BST not the properties. The right most node is not the largest and the left most is not the smallest.

So far I have created code that I think would work for most cases except negative cases.

```
typedef Struct BST
{
    int data;
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
}Tree;
```

The above is just the structure of the node

```
int largest_leaf(Tree *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Heyall\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(head -> right == NULL && head -> left == NULL)
    {
        printf("head -> data: %d\n", head -> data);
        return head -> data;
    }
    int i = largest_leaf(head -> left);
    int r = i;
    i = largest_leaf(head -> right);    
    if(i > r)
    {
        r = i;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I know my code may be confusing. But to simplfy it, since this is in a shape of a tree I am going to be traversing to one edge (In this case the left) and then return the leaf value and do the same for every value there after.

My question is how do I fix the problem of getting a zero for the case of all negative values in the leaf node.

edit: the tree is not empty

Comment: So what do you want the function to do if it is indeed called with an empty tree? You need to decide what the API definition should be first and after that it is simple to code. For example, you may define that the function returns `MIN_INT` if the tree is empty. Or you may change the function to return a boolean and accept a pointer to an `int` that is updated with the max only if the function returns true.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to find the largest leaf node in a BST but it only has the shape of a BST not the properties. The right most node is not the largest and the left most is not the smallest.

You have to traverse the whole tree and use the same basic algorithm you'd use for an array. Instead of 0 as the smallest number, use the smallest possible integer: [INT_MIN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

[As mentioned by kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208516/largest-leaf-node-in-a-tree-how-to-prevent-getting-a-0-when-leaf-nodes-are-negat/65208651#comment115282201_65208516), you need to consider what happens when the tree is empty. Does it return `INT_MIN`? Do you need a separate error flag?